# Generate all possible element combinations with 2 lists

Tags: python, data-structures

Consider we have 2 lists (The size of these lists may vary):

features = ['F1', 'F2', 'F3' ]
values = [0, 1]

and I want to get all possible combinations of any possible size (image to represent it):

[image]

The idea is to obtain the combinations illustrated inside all the nodes (F1_0, F1_0 F2_0 ...). Currently, I have tried using recursion:

```
features = ['F1', 'F2', 'F3']
query = ''
values = [0, 1]

def datatree(query,features):
    if features:
        feature = features.pop(0)
        query+= feature
        for i in values:
            datatree(query+ '_' + str(i)+' ', features)
    else:
        print(query)

datatree(query, features)
```

But I'm not designing it correctly because when it reaches F1_0 F2_1 and has to continue, features is empty (Which I don't understand because in that subroutine the stack should have still F3, right?)

```
Output:

F1_0 F2_0 F3_0 
F1_0 F2_0 F3_1 
F1_0 F2_1 
F1_1
```

Is there any other approach you think can help me or something that I am failing to understand?

Comment: Check the value of features after calling your function to see what goes wrong. Hint: don’t mix recursion and mutation unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You're are a genius!! Thanks so much for the hint. For some reason in my head the list in F2_1 still has F3, that's why I was getting so frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are only using one list for `feature`. Since `feature` is [passed by reference](https://realpython.com/python-pass-by-reference/), therefore, for example, when you have reached the end of the stack `F_3` and go back up a level, the element `F_3` is already popped out and is not in `feature` for the next time you pass it to `datatree`.

To fix it, you need to pass in the copy of the `feature` when call ing `datatree`:

```
from copy import copy
features = ['F1', 'F2', 'F3']
query = ''
values = [0, 1]

def datatree(query,features):
    if features:
        feature = features.pop(0)
        query+= feature
        for i in values:
            datatree(query+ '_' + str(i)+' ', copy(features))
    else:
        print(query)

datatree(query, features)
```

gives:

```
F1_0 F2_0 F3_0 
F1_0 F2_0 F3_1 
F1_0 F2_1 F3_0 
F1_0 F2_1 F3_1 
F1_1 F2_0 F3_0 
F1_1 F2_0 F3_1 
F1_1 F2_1 F3_0 
F1_1 F2_1 F3_1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation about variables passed by reference! This was exactly the major thing I didn't understand about the issue

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.product(values, repeat=len(features))` to generate the possible permutations of values, e.g. `[0,0,0],[0,0,1],...,[1,1,1]`.

Then use a list comprehension to apply the value as a suffix to the feature at the corresponding position. We match the value's position to the feature using `zip` -- i.e. `zip(['F1', 'F2'], [0,1])` returns an iterable of `[('F1', 0), ('F2', 1)]`.

```py
from itertools import product

def datatree(features, values):
    value_combinations = product(values, repeat=len(features))
    return [
        " ".join(
            f"{feature}_{value}" for feature, value in zip(features, combination)
        )
        for combination in value_combinations
    ]

features = ['F1', 'F2', 'F3']
values = [0, 1]

# returns ['F1_0 F2_0 F3_0', 'F1_0 F2_0 F3_1', 'F1_0 F2_1 F3_0', 'F1_0 F2_1 F3_1', 'F1_1 F2_0 F3_0', 'F1_1 F2_0 F3_1', 'F1_1 F2_1 F3_0', 'F1_1 F2_1 F3_1']
datatree(features, values)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, this also solves the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the content of all the nodes. Here is the final code:

```
features = ['F1', 'F2', 'F3']
values = [0, 1]
query=''

def datatree(query,features,feature_index):
    print(query)
    if feature_index<len(features):
        query += features[feature_index]
        for i in values:
            datatree(query+ '_' + str(i)+' ', features, feature_index+1)
datatree(query, features,0)
```